# SQL/SQL Server - Query to average DL_MAX against all dates in the data except the last day and than divide it by the average to calculate percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to learn sql on everyday work examples. I have a set of data below , my main task will be to Average DL Max against all dates leaving the last date and than to divide it with the average to get the %. Any support in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks

Sorry guys for not clarifying it in detail I have done the editing on the data set to be more specific

`date                cellname        DL_MAX
19/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  104886195
20/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  117873600
21/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  154891951
22/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  108345713
23/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  122292588
24/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  116437819
25/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  108978292
26/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  109196628
27/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  105037138
28/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  93869738
29/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  114865651
30/06/2016 0:00     408_SecureCell  109684102
19/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  104886195
20/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  117873600
21/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  154891951
22/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  108345713
23/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  122292588
24/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  116437819
25/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  108978292
26/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  109196628
27/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  105037138
28/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  93869738
29/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  114865651
30/06/2016 0:00     409_SecureCell  109684102`

Some code i have written with the help of searching the stackoverflow :)

1st query AVG the (DL_MAX) leaving the last one day

`select cellname, AVG(DL_MAX) from DLMAX 
WHERE cellname = '408_Securecell'
and date < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,1, GETDATE()), 0)
Group by Cellname;`

2nd query

`select cellname, AVG(DL_MAX) from DLMAX 
WHERE cellname = '408_Securecell'
and date = dateadd(DAY, datediff(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0)
Group by Cellname;`

Dont know how to proceed further. Kindly help

Sorry guys for not clarifying it in detail I have done the editing on the data set to be more specific

Comment: OP can you please clarify what you mean by "average DL Max against all dates leaving the last date and than to divide it with the average to get the %." Divide what average by what average? Are you looking for a single value or a computation for each row?

Comment: I am looking for one value for e.g.
408_SecureCell = DL_MAX(30-06-2016) /Avg(DL_MAX from 19-6-2016 to 29-6-2016)
409_SecureCell = DL_MAX(30-06-2016) /Avg(DL_MAX from 19-6-2016 to 29-6-2016)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  cellname, date,
  DL_MAX / rolling_average * 100 as percentage 
from (
  select 
     cellname, date, max(date) over (partition by cellname) as max_date,
    AVG(DL_MAX) over (
      partition by cellname 
      order by date 
      rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) as rolling_average,
    DL_MAX
    from DLMAX
  ) sq
where date = max_date -- gives only the rows having date = the latest date in the table
```

Comment: From your query what I get is that you're averaging the current row and preceding rows average and then divide current row value by it, correct? But I think the question is simpler and he wants the each row value to be divided by the total average(minus last days value). Good effort though.

Comment: No, this subquery gives each row another column which equates to the average DL_MAX for all previous dates excluding the current row (for that particular cellname). In the outer query that row's DL_MAX is divided by the rolling average and shown as a percentage.

Comment: This gives the scalar value OP asked for, for each row - I'm not sure I understand his question properly though.

Comment: Yeah I know. After your answer am also confused on what OP wants

Comment: sorry guys for my inability to explain, if this e.g helps
I am looking for one value for e.g.
408_SecureCell = DL_MAX(30-06-2016) /Avg(DL_MAX from 19-6-2016 to 29-6-2016)
409_SecureCell = DL_MAX(30-06-2016) /Avg(DL_MAX from 19-6-2016 to 29-6-2016)

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you that. If you want just one particular cellname, add that to the where clause. If it's possible that some cellnames do not get a new row each day, this query won't work and you'll have to add another window function to pull the most recent date for each cell, and add another part to the where clause to filter it based on date.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your support i am getting this error"Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
"

Comment: Should be fixed now, give it a shot

Comment: Thanks Eric for your support. Much appreciated., Awesome worked like a charm but how to ignore the zeros .

Comment: Ignore fields that are zero, or zeroes at the end of the number? To ignore rows where percentage=0, add to your where clause " ... and DL_MAX != 0 and rolling_average != 0". To format the percentage so it doesn't show trailing zeroes, cast it to a float, or better yet handle it in the presentation layer. Don't forget to mark my answer if it solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte (Average)
AS
(select AVG(DL_MAX) 
from    DLMAX 
WHERE   cellname = '408_Securecell'
        and date < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,1, GETDATE()), 0)
Group by Cellname
)
SELECT  CAST(DL_MAX AS decimal)/(select average from cte)
FROM    DLMAX
```